# Getting same result with less code with PythonWin ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, for-loop, code-review

I have finished writing code and it does what I need without having any error. However, I am wondering if there is any option to get the same result in fewer lines, pecially the for loop inside the UpdateCursor.

I am using ArcMap 10.7.1

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# @Author: Daniel Ibáñez Campos
# @Abstract:

# Import the arcpy and os modules
import arcpy
import os
import sys

#=============================================================================
# Functions 
#=============================================================================

# Define functions here

#def myfunction1( text ):
    #print "This is myfunction 1"
    #print text

#=============================================================================
# Main script
#=============================================================================

# It lets the user know that the script has started
print "Script starting"
# Set up the workspace environment
arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\python_data"
# Overwrite files by default
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True 

#=============================================================================
# Call functions here
#=============================================================================

#myfunction1("Example text")

# Input feature class (shapefile)
fc = "10_and_more_acres.shp"
# Creates the new field name "CAUSE_TEXT"
newfield = "CAUSE_TEXT"
# Defines the new field type (This is a text field)
fieldtype = "TEXT"
# Validates that the new field created has a valid name
fieldname = arcpy.ValidateFieldName(newfield)
# This function clears up the field name 
print "cleaned up fieldname:", fieldname
# Call addField to create the new field
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, fieldname, fieldtype, "", "",50)
# Tells the user that the new field has been created
print "New field created!"
# This function generates the correct syntax for a where clause
delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters (fc, "CAUSE_TEXT")
# Opens update cursor on column "CAUSE"
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["CAUSE_TEXT", "CAUSE"])
# For each row where the where clause is true 
for row in cursor:
    # Insert
    if row[1] == 0 and 14:
        row[0] = "Unknown / Unidentified"
    if row[1] == 1:
        row[0] = "Lightning"
    if row[1] == 2:
        row[0] = "Equipment Use"
    if row[1] == 3:
        row[0] = "Smoking"
    if row[1] == 4:
        row[0] = "Campfire"
    if row[1] == 5:
        row[0] = "Debris"
    if row[1] == 6:
        row[0] = "Railroad"
    if row[1] == 7:
        row[0] = "Arson"
    if row[1] == 8:
        row[0] = "Playing with fire"
    if row[1] == 9:
        row[0] = "Miscellaneous"
    if row[1] == 10:
        row[0] = "Vehicle"
    if row[1] == 11:
        row[0] = "Powerline"
    if row[1] == 12:
        row[0] = "Firefighter Training"
    if row[1] == 13:
        row[0] = "Non-Firefighter Training"
    #if row[1] == 14:
        #row[0] = "Unknown / Unidentified"
    if row[1] == 15:
        row[0] = "Structure"
    if row[1] == 16:
        row[0] = "Aircraft"
    if row[1] == 17:
        row[0] = "Volcanic"
    if row[1] == 18:
        row[0] = "Escaped Prescribed Burn"
    if row[1] == 19:
        row[0] = "Illegal Alien Campfire"
    # Update rows in the attribute table
    cursor.updateRow(row)
# Clear up the cursor
del cursor

# Tells user that the script has finished
print "End of script"
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions requesting a review of working code should be asked at the Code Review Stack Exchange - https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/code-review/info

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries):

> The main operations on a dictionary are storing a value with some key
>   and extracting the value given the key.

```
d = {1:"Lightning", 2:"Equipent use", ... }
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["CAUSE_TEXT", "CAUSE"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[1] in d: #Check if value of row[1] exists in dictionary
            row[0] = d[row[1]]
        #else:
        #   row[0] = "Missing"
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```